# Upload on-premises content to SharePoint Online how to retrieve the logs (using powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure, sharepoint

Based on the following [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-on-premises-content-to-SharePoint-Online-555049c6-15ef-45a6-9a1f-a1ef673b867c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) i'm uploading file server information to SharePoint online.
Everything is working except for Step 7: Processing and Monitoring your SPO Migration.
The description there is:

> Checking job status You can check the status of your job by viewing
>   the real time updates posted in the Azure storage account queue by
>   using the Encryption.EncryptionKey returned in step 6.
>
> Viewing logs If you’re using your own Azure storage account, you can
>   look into the manifest container in the Azure Storage for logs of
>   everything that happened. At this stage, it is now safe to delete
>   those containers if you don’t want to keep them as backup in Azure.
>
> If there were errors or warnings, .err and .wrn files will be created
>   in the manifest container.
>
> If you’re using the temporary Azure storage created by
>   Invoke-SPOMigrationEncryptUploadSubmit in step 6, the import log SAS
>   URL can be obtained by decrypting the Azure queue message with the
>   “Event” value “JobLogFileCreate”. With the import log SAS URL, you can
>   download the log file and decrypt it with the same encryption key as
>   returned in Step 6.

I have the encryptionKey and ReportingQueueUri, there is no explanation on how to use them, trying with Azure Storage Explorer i opened the reporting queue but its all encrypted there and there is no option to use the encryptionKey.

If anyone did this or know how to i'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

One has to use two other cmdlets, `Get-SPOMigrationJobProgress` and `Get-SPOMigrationJobStatus`

```
$job = Invoke-SPOMigrationEncryptUploadSubmit       `
                  -SourceFilesPath $sourceFiles     `
                  -SourcePackagePath $targetPackage `
                  -Credentials $creds               `
                  -TargetWebUrl $targetWebUrl 

$encryption = $job.Encryption

$queueLink = $job.ReportingQueueUri.AbsoluteUri

$jobID = $job.jobid

Get-SPOMigrationJobProgress -AzureQueueUri $queueLink   `
                            -Credentials $creds         `
                            -TargetWebUrl $targetWebUrl `
                            -JobIds $jobID              `
                            -EncryptionParameters $encryption

Get-SPOMigrationJobStatus -TargetWebUrl $targetWebUrl -Credentials $creds -JobId $jobID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the thing is that i can see that there was an error on the copy but cannot see what is the error, for that i need to get the logfile.

Comment: the two cmdlets at the bottom... Get-SPOMigrationJobProgress & Get-SPOMigrationJobStatus will generate a txt log file in your working directory.  check your c:\windows\system32 if you were running this in the ISE, or they might be in C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0    .   the file names are.... MigrationJobStatus-date-time-#.log

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.